# What kind of scope does the variable belong to if we define a function variable outside of this function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

Consider this code

```js
function foo(){
     foo.count = 1;
     console.log(foo.count);
}
foo.count = 2;
foo();
console.log(foo.count);
```

I expected the result would be 1, 2, but the actual result is 1, 1. 
This is confusing; I assigned a new value to `foo.count = 2`, but it seems not to work.

```js
function foo(){
     console.log(foo.count);
}
foo.count = 2;
foo();
console.log(foo.count);
```

If I delete the assignment code in `foo()` function, the result is 2, 2.

So I want to know what scope the variable has if we define a function variable outside of this function? Does `foo.count` belong to the function scope or global scope?

Comment: this isn't a scope issue; you set a property to a value, then you ran the function, which set the property to a new value.

Comment: This would print 1,2 `function foo(){
     foo.count = 1;
     console.log(foo.count);
}
foo();
foo.count = 2;
console.log(foo.count);`

Comment: @Claies thank you very much. your  answer lead me to figure out what i was misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original code, when you execute `foo()` in line 6 you're setting the value to `1`